# PWA native install prompt not firing on first page load

Tags: android, web, mobile, frontend, progressive-web-apps

I've implemented a PWA for my website that has been triggering the native install prompt. Recently, I noticed the initial install prompt has not been triggering on Android version 13+. I tested this in Browserstack with a number of devices and concluded that the issue is indeed only on Android versions 13+.

Strangely enough, a refresh of the site will trigger the install prompt on Android 13+. Whereas, on version 12 and below, it seems the install prompt will appear once it detects user engagement, i.e. scrolling, button presses.

Was there some change in Android 13+?